# Setter not called

Tags: nativescript, getter-setter, setter

I am building a simple location tracker in NativeScript. The current location and the past ones are all stored in a view model called `scope` and constantly updated. When new location data is available, the setter addLocation is called.

```
var scope = new observableModule.fromObject({

    "locations": [],
    "lastLocation": {
        "latitude": 0,
        "longitude": 0,
        "altitude": 0,
        "horizontalAccuracy": 0,
        "verticalAccuracy": 0,
        "direction": 0,
        "timestamp": "No location yet",
        "speed": 0
    },

    set addLocation(loc) {
        console.log('Setter called');
        this.lastLocation = loc;
        this.locations.push(loc);
    }
});
```

This is imported as view model to the page. The setter is called simply like this:

```
scope.addLocation = loc;
```

where `loc` is the output of `watchLocation()` from the GeoLocation plugin.

It seems that the setter is not triggered though. The console message never appears. I tried adding other setters, but they also don't work. Getters are working. What is going on?

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `scope.addLocation(loc)` instead?

Comment: That's not how you call a setter. However that was indeed a typo, it should be `addLocation` and not `lastLocation`. Fixed.